# I have 2 arrays - users and onlineUsers, how would I use Vue.js to loop over and display all users and apply class if that user exists in both arrays?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects called `users` and every object has a property called `username`

```
let users = [
    {
        username: 'Test1'
    },
    {
        username: 'Test12'
    }
]
```

I also have an array called `onlineUsers` which also contains objects with a property called `username`:

```
let onlineUsers = [
    {
        username: 'Test1'
    }
]
```

Right now I'm looping over users and displaying the users like this:

```
    <p v-for='member in users'>
        <span class='username'>{{ member.username }}</span>
    </p>
```

And now I'm trying to figure out how to apply a special class to the users which are also present in both the `users` and `onlineUsers` array. The problem is I can't figure out how. I tried double `v-for` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:class` and `.some()`  array helper function like:

- `:class` is used for conditional binding
- `.some()` returns true if at least one condition is true

VUE :

```
<p v-for='member in users'>
        <span class='username' :class="{special : onlineUsers.some(v=>v.username === member.username) }">{{ member.username }}</span>
</p>
```

CSS :

```css
.special: {
...
}
```

Reference :

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html
- [array_some_mdn_reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#:%7E:text=The%20some()%20method%20executes,Otherwise%2C%20some()%20returns%20false%20.)